# Furnace keeps turning off

Tags: furnace

My 10 year old furnace turns off after about 3 to 5 mins of running and I get error code 33 for a Bryant furnace, but if I leave the door off the furnace runs just fine. I cleaned as much as I could and even took the filter out to supply more air.

Comment: Have you looked up what code 33 corresponds to?

Comment: "but if I leave the door off the furnace runs just fine" - this makes me think you're having an airflow problem and the burners cannot acquire enough oxygen for adequate burning.

Comment: Filter is for the air flow through the ductwork. Taking the door off - and some error codes (but I have no idea what this one is) and symptoms like you describe - would point to an issue of *combustion air*. Which is supposed to be separate for CO/CO2/etc. reasons.

Comment: How about telling us what model Bryant furnace you have...

Answer (score 2):

Most probably Dirty air filters or failing High limit switch.

#33 LIMIT CIRCUIT FAULT

With time, the filter becomes clogged and restricts airflow to the equipment’s heat exchanger.

When this happens, the heat exchanger overheats, forcing the **high-limit** switch to trip and the furnace to cycle off.

Comment: Could be a combination of dirty filters and an oversized furnace and/or too many room vents closed.  Bottom line is there needs to be a minimum amount of room air flowing through the furnace.  If the furnace is on the large side for your home, it doesn't take much to reduce the air flow to "too low".  Opening the door may bypass or delay the furnace's ability to *detect* the low air flow problem.  That's like plugging your ears when you hear a fire alarm.